# 'ListWrapper' object has no attribute 'get_config' error when doing gridsearch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, grid-search

I have to do grid search on my DNN. But I am getting an error on GridSearchCV function.
Here is the code for creating and compiling the model I used and also when I tried to do the grid search.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
import keras,sklearn
import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'
import tensorflow as tf
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier


CASE = 1
if CASE == 1:
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(L,input_shape=(L,), activation ="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(20, activation= 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(20, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
    nepoch = 400
if CASE == 2:
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(L, input_shape=(L,), activation= 'sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation= 'sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation= 'sigmoid'))
    nepoch = 400
    
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
             optimizer = optimizer,
             metrics = ['accuracy'])
model_gridsearch = KerasClassifier(build_fn=model, 
                        epochs=1, 
                        batch_size=50, 
                        verbose=1)

optimizer = ['sgd', 'rmsprop', 'adadelta', 'adam', 'adamax'] 

param_grid = dict(optimizer=optimizer)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model_gridsearch, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=1, cv=4)
grid_result = grid.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

The error I am getting is on `grid_result = grid.fit(x_train,y_train)`
which says `AttributeError: 'ListWrapper' object has no attribute 'get_config'`
My tensorflow version is 2.8.0 if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with optimizer list. In case of multiple optimizers, you can use optimizer wrapper API `tfa.optimizers.MultiOptimizer`.

```
optimizers = [
    tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-4),
    tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-4),
    tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(learning_rate=1e-4),
    tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-2),
    tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax(learning_rate=1e-4)
]
optimizers_and_layers = [(optimizers[0], model.layers[0:]), (optimizers[1], model.layers[1:2]),(optimizers[2], model.layers[3:4]), (optimizers[3:], .......]
optimizer = tfa.optimizers.MultiOptimizer(optimizers_and_layers)
combined_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])
```